# Im not Getting the Button Release Toast in OnTouchListners

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

The issue is im not getting the Button release Toast.
i've a simple view in xml on which im performing onTouch.

```
hidenBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int action = event.getActionMasked();
                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        firstTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                            || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Released", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        secondTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        if(secondTime-firstTime>=5000){
                            //do your actions here,prev,curr are fields in a class
                            ShowDialog();
                        }
                        else{
                            firstTime=0;
                            secondTime=0;
                        }
                    }
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `OnTouchListener` like this:

```
hidenBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getActionMasked();
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                firstTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                    || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Released", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                secondTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                if(secondTime-firstTime>=5000){
                    //do your actions here,prev,curr are fields in a class
                    ShowDialog();
                }
                else{
                    firstTime=0;
                    secondTime=0;
                }
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

You are returning `false` at `ACTION_DOWN` which means you are not consuming your touch event, so no other steps of the same event are triggered. Therefore you need to return `true` in the `ACTION_DOWN` so you can intercept `ACTION_UP`.

Comment: Thanks. now the issue is when i press and hold for 5 sec nothings happend untill i release the button after 5 sec. i want a behavior that after 5 sec i will not wait for action_up and run the code.

Comment: Add the details to your question so I can answer it.